# Disable Global Temporary table creation during hibernate setup

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm seeing the following logs when application -

WARNING: Failed Query Report SQL=create global temporary table HT_TABLENAME (PRIMARY_COLUMN number(100,0) not null) on commit delete rows; time=567 ms;

This means that hibernate is trying to create a global temporary table for all hibernate POJOs defined with hierarchy.

The number of such POJOs are pretty high in the codebase and hence trying to get the local up and running takes a lot of time. Is there any parameter that can be added which will disable such validations?

Did try to -Djavax.persistence.validation.mode=none set this as a system parameter for my local run but it doesn't seem to have helped.

I believe all hibernate validations run irrespective of this parameter.

Is there any way to prevent global temporary table creation during hibernate setup during application startup?

We are using hibernate 5.0.2 with Oracle database.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the following information: what version of Hibernate? What database?

Comment: Did you try to comment a line in `persistence.xml` file which is like: `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />`.

Comment: We are using hibernate 5.0.2 with Oracle database.

Comment: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is not setup in the configuration. But, create is not really what I'm looking for here. hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none also seems to create global temporary table.